# Error showing "unfortunatey the app has stopped working" in Android

Tags: android

i am trying to make an app in android but when m trying to run the app in my mobile phone, whenever i click on the button it says "unfortunately the app has stopped working", here is my code, can anybody tell me what m u doing wrong here

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText titleEditText;
EditText noteEditText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button saveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            titleEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);

            noteEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Note);
            titleEditText.setEnabled(false);
            noteEditText.setEnabled(false);
        //saveButton.setText("Clicked!");
        }
    });
}
```

`

Comment: where is your logcat???

Comment: there is no error in your code.. i tried it and it is working fine. Just clean and run again your project. If still face any problem, post log here. Check XML once if id of editText there is `note` then make id in activity as `note` instead of `Note`

Answer (score 2):

put these two lines out of onclick listener and change Note id of Edittext in you xml file to small letters which should be 'note'.

```
titleEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);

noteEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.note);
```

Answer (score 0):

check if there is Note and title in your activity_main
if the exception is NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

in design or XML part where you have placed all these Edittexts please verify whether or not the id is matching or not. these type of errors often take place when there is id mismatch in UI elements.